# How to build bash command from variable?

Tags: bash

I have a bash variable:

```
A="test; ls"
```

I want to use it as part of a call:

```
echo $A
```

I'm expecting it to be expanded into:

```
echo test; ls
```

However, it is expanded:

```
echo "test;" "ls"
```

How is it possible to achieve what I want? The only solution I can think of is this:

```
bash -c "echo $A"
```

Maybe there is something more elegant?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you really want metacharacters like `;` to be honored, you need to use `eval`, and using `eval` is prone with security risks if not done with great care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building compound commands, running redirections, etc., then you need to use eval:

```
A="test; ls"
eval "$A"
```

However, it's **far better not to do this**. A typical use case that follows good practices follows:

```
my_cmd=( something --some-arg "another argument with spaces" )
if [[ $foo ]]; then
  my_cmd+=( --foo="$foo" )
fi
"${my_cmd[@]}"
```

Unlike the `eval` version, this can only run a single command line, and will run it exactly as-given -- meaning that even if `foo='$(rm -rf /)'` you won't get your hard drive wiped. :)

---

If you absolutely must use `eval`, or are forming a shell command to be used in a context where it will necessarily be shell-evaluated (for instance, passed on a `ssh` command line), you can achieve a hybrid approach using `printf %q` to form command lines safe for eval:

```
printf -v cmd_str 'ls -l %q; exit 1' "some potentially malicious string"
eval "$cmd_str"
```

---

See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for more details on the `eval` command and why it should be used only with great care, or [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a general discussion of pitfalls and best practices around programmatically constructing commands. (Note that `bash -c "$cmd_str"` is equivalent to eval in terms of security impact, and requires the same precautions to use safely).

Answer (score -1):

dont use echo, just have the var

`A="echo test; ls"`

`$A`

Comment: This doesn't actually work -- it treats the semicolon as data, not syntax (which is, from a security perspective, a feature rather than a bug).